# Postgres UPSERT - don't update if all data the same?

Tags: postgresql, unique, upsert

I am using Postgres 9.6. I want to update a record if *anything* about it is different, but keep it the same if not.

This is my SQL, slightly simplified because my table actually has many more fields (run via psycopg2):

```
query = "INSERT INTO cap(scheme, year, code) "
query += "VALUES(%s, %s, %s) "
query += "ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING"
cursor.execute(query, ('abc', 2015, 'twu'))
```

However, if I run it twice with exactly the same values, I get two records in the database.

How can I amend this query so that providing the exact same values does not create a new record?

I've tried to read the [ON CONFLICT UPDATE documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) but don't know how to adapt it for my case. In particular, it looks to me like `DO NOTHING` should not insert a row (the docs say: *"ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING simply avoids inserting a row as its alternative action"*), but it does insert a new row.

Comment: Do you have a primary or unique key defined for that table? [edit] your question and add the complete `create table` statement for the table `cap` (including all indexes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ...` needs a unique constraint to catch a conflict, e.g.

```
create table cap(
    scheme text, 
    year int, 
    code text, 
    unique(scheme, year, code) -- ! added
);
```

With the unique constraint multiple execution of this query

```
INSERT INTO cap(scheme, year, code)
VALUES('abc', 2015, 'twu')
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```

will insert the row only once.